# Why the smart pointer auto_ptr cannot be referenced at that time?

Tags: c++, pointers

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
class MyClass
{
public:
    int i;
    MyClass(int s) {
        i=s;
    }
    ~MyClass() {
        cout<<"This class has been destroied.  "<<i<<endl;
    }
    void myFunc() {
        cout<<"myFunc() done.  "<<i<<endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    auto_ptr<MyClass> ptr1(new MyClass(1));
    auto_ptr<MyClass>ptr2(new MyClass(2));
    ptr1->myFunc();
    ptr2->myFunc();
    cout<<"test 1 done\n"<<endl;

    ptr2 = ptr1;
    ptr2->myFunc();
    //ptr1->myFunc();
    cout<<"test 2 done\n"<<endl;
}
/*
$ ./a.out 
myFunc() done.  1
myFunc() done.  2
test 1 done

This class has been destroied.  2
myFunc() done.  1
test 2 done
 * */
```

If the above `ptr1->myFunc();` is not commented out, then the result is below. But I cannot understand it. I think that ptr1 is not destroied at that time...
Who could help to further explain it?

```
$ ./a.out 
myFunc() done.  1
myFunc() done.  2
test 1 done

This class has been destroied.  2
myFunc() done.  1
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Comment: `auto_ptr` has been deprecated, see if your compiler supports `unique_ptr` already

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The old `auto_ptr` has very odd behaviour when copied or assigned. It has *transfer* semantics rather than copy semantics. This means than when you say `ptr2 = ptr1;`, `ptr1` has actually changed: It no longer points to anything. (And the thing that `ptr2` pointed to originally has of course been deleted.)

Therefore, you mustn't use `ptr1` after you assigned *from* it (until you assign *to* it again or reset it).

---

The fact that this behaviour is so awkward, although such a smart pointer is a very desirable thing, indicates that there was something missing in the language. The correct solution requires rvalue references, and the new `unique_ptr`, which tries to solve the same problem as `auto_ptr`, behaves more sensibly: You cannot copy or copy-assign it at all, but you can *move* it — which is a new part of the language:

```
unique_ptr<MyClass> ptr1(new MyClass), ptr2(new MyClass);

ptr2 = std::move(ptr1);  // now it's clear that ptr1 is no longer usable

assert(!ptr1);
```

Answer (score 1):

When you do `ptr2 = ptr1;` you are deleting the object currently pointed to by `ptr2` which now points to the object previously pointed to by `ptr1`. `ptr1` has set itself to point to *null*, because that is the semantics of `auto_ptr` on copies. You then try to dereference null, and are lucky enough to get a crash and figure your code is wrong.